# Why does the position of arguments matter in cons?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket, cons

Simple code:

```
> (cons null (cons 1 2))
'(() 1 . 2)
> (cons (cons 1 2)  null)
'((1 . 2))
```

Initially, I'd expect the result to be the same. I can think of some vague explanations, but would also like to hear a strong point from someone knowledgeable.

Why is the result different?

Comment: the first is `(() . (1 . 2))`, the second is `((1 . 2) . ())`. if `cons` were `append`, and literals were singletons, *then* it would be equal: `(append null (append '(1) '(2))) == '(1 2) == (append (append '(1) '(2)) null)`. or in pseudocode, `[]+([1]+[2]) == ([1]+[2])+[]`, simply because empty list is the identity element wrt the list append operation.

Comment: thus the answer to your question seems to be, "because `cons` is not `append`". if that is indeed what you thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the parlance of mathematics, some operations are *commutative*. Addition is commutative, so `(+ 1 2)` and `(+ 2 1)` both have the same result. Division is not commutative; `(/ 1 2)` and `(/ 2 1)` do not have the same result.

The OP expectation that `(cons null (cons 1 2))` and `(cons null (cons 1 2))` should have the same result is in fact the expectation that `cons` is a commutative procedure. It is not. If `cons` *were* commutative, then `(cons 1 2)` and `(cons 2 1)` would be equivalent. But:

```
> (cons 1 2)
(1 . 2)
> (cons 2 1)
(2 . 1)
```

The `cons` procedure creates a `cons` cell, which has two components traditionally called the `car` and the `cdr`; it creates the `cons` cell from two arguments. The first argument is placed in the `car` of the cell, and the second argument is placed in the `cdr` of the cell. With `(cons 1 2)`, 1 is placed in the `car`, and 2 is placed in the `cdr`; but with `(cons 2 1)` the 2 is placed in the `car`, while the 1 is placed in the `cdr`. You can see that `(cons 1 2)` and `(cons 2 1)` must necessarily be different since the `car` and `cdr` of the `cons` cell are distinct.

OP example `(cons null (cons 1 2))` places the empty list in the `car` of a `cons` cell, and places the cell `(1 . 2)` (itself created by another call to `cons`) in the `cdr` of that cell. This is the *dotted list* (described below) `(() . (1 . 2))`; such a dotted list is usually represented in the REPL as `(() 1 . 2)`.

But with `(cons (cons 1 2)  null)` the cell `(1 . 2)` is instead placed in the `car` of a `cons` cell, with the empty list place in the `cdr` of that cell: `((1 . 2) . ())`.

Now, in Lisps a list is a chain of `cons` cells terminating with the empty list. A chain like `(1 . (2 . 3))` is sometimes called a *dotted list* or an *improper list*; this is a chain of `cons` cells that does not terminate with the empty list. In the REPL you will often see `(1 . (2 . 3))` represented as `(1 2 . 3)`. On the other hand, a chain like `(1 . (2 . ()))` is then called a *proper list*; this is a chain of `cons` cells that *does* terminate with the empty list. You would see this represented in the REPL as `(1 2)`. Usually when someone uses the unqualified term *list*, they mean *proper list*.

So, OP code `((1 . 2) . ())` is equivalent to the proper list `((1 . 2))`, which contains the single member `(1 . 2)`, and this is certainly different from the dotted list `(() 1 . 2)`.

There is another procedure, `append`, which would behave as OP expected. Both `(append null (append '(1) '(2)))` and `(append (append '(1) '(2))  null)` evaluate to `'(1 2)`. These last two expressions evaluate to the same result because the empty list is the *identity element* for the operation `append`. That is, joining a nonempty list of items with the empty list gives back a copy of the nonempty list. Similarly, joining an empty list with a nonempty list gives back a copy of the nonempty list. But `append` is not commutative; `append` returns a list containing the elements of the first list followed by the elements of the second list. So, `(append '(1 2) '(3 4))` --> `'(1 2 3 4)`, but `(append '(3 4) '(1 2))` --> `'(3 4 1 2)`.

There is another relevant mathematical property: *associativity*. Addition is associative, i.e., `(+ 1 (+ 2 3))` and `(+ (+ 1 2) 3)` both evaluate to the same result. Using infix notation, `1 + (2 + 3)` and `(1 + 2) + 3` both evaluate to the same result. This has an interesting consequence. Since the grouping is not important, it makes sense to simply write the above infix expressions as `1 + 2 + 3`. The corresponding prefix expression is `(+ 1 2 3)`, and Lisps do support this way of expressing addition for multiple operands.

`cons` is *not* associative. Since `cons` creates a pair from its arguments, it can't be associative. With `(cons 1 2)` the pair `(1 . 2)` is created. With `(cons 1 (cons 2 3))` the pair `(2 . 3)` is placed in the `cdr` of another pair, and the result is `(1 . (2 . 3))` (probably represented in the REPL as `(1 2 . 3)`). But with `(cons (cons 1  2) 3)` the pair `(1 . 2)` is created and placed in the `car` of another pair, resulting in `((1 . 2) . 3)`. Note that, since `cons` is not associative, an expression like `(cons 1 2 3)` does not make sense; the grouping of operations is unclear.

But `append` *is* associative. With `(append '(1) '(2))` the list `(1 2)` is created. With `(append '(1) (append '(2) '(3)))` the list `(2 3)` is created, and the list `(1)` is then joined with `(2 3)`, resulting in `(1 2 3)`. With `(append (append '(1) '(2)) '(3))` the list `(1 2)` is created and then joined with the list `(3)`, also resulting in the list `(1 2 3)`. Since grouping is not important here, it makes sense to simply write `(append '(1) '(2) '(3))`, and again, as with addition, Lisps do support this way of expressing append operations.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `cons` is also not associative, so `(cons a (cons b c))` is not the same as `(cons (cons a b) c)`.

Comment: @tfb -- Done. A discussion of associativity seem to warrant bringing `append` into the conversation, especially given that a commenter under the OP question mentioned `append`.

Comment: I'm now having to carefully avoid thinking about how you could make lists into a group under `append`.  You'd need 'negative lists` such that `(append (append x y) z))` was x, for any `y`...

Comment: @tfb -- lists do not form a group under `append`, but they do form a monoid.... I'll probably leave that bit out of the answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, but monoids are one of those things that, well, if it's not a monoid it's barely anything :-) (this is a joke: I know there are magmas, and I know really that monoids are worth studying, even though I'm a physicist so I inly really believe in groups...)

Answer (score 4):

See the "box and pointer" diagram in SICP [here](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2). The `cons` is a *constructor* of pairs - it just puts two things together. If we generalize this notion of pairing things, we can build trees. In scheme/racket, lists are just a special case of trees (with each "left" branch holding an element of the list and each right branch holding the rest of the list).

The shorthand: Since it's cumbersome writing `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 null)))`, we simplify: `'(1 2 3)`. Note that the last `null` (or `'()`) is omitted in the shorthand. If it weren't a null and it were a `4`, we would get the following shorthand version: `'(1 2 3 . 4)`. The dot suggests that the right hand side of the construction is *not* a list.

For the first example, `null` is just an element of the list - occurring on a left branch. For the second example, `null` is the rightmost element - suggesting the end of the list.

```
    / \          Null is displayed as () in
   /   \         the shorthand version. Whenever
 null            a pair does not have a list
       / \       on the right, we see a dot.
      /   \ 
     1     2


       / \       Note here that the null
      /   \      is on the last right-most
          null   branch. This null is not
    / \          shown in the shorthand.
   /   \
  1     2
```

Comment: `cons` isn't just a constructor of pairs, it is a constructor of _ordered_ pairs. I wouldn't say that `'(1 2 3)` is shorthand for `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 null)))`, because `cons` evaluates its arguments. `'(x)` is quite different compared with `(cons x null)`.

Comment: Maybe I should've said that the `list` syntax is a shorthand for (cons ... (cons ... null)) since there's a distinction between list syntax and quoting.